# Symfony3 does not read the environment variables on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, symfony

Everything works fine on my local machine. `printenv | grep SYMFONY` on my local machine prints me this

```
SYMFONY__DATABASE_HOST=127.0.0.1
SYMFONY__DATABASE_NAME=database
SYMFONY__DATABASE_PASSWORD=root
SYMFONY__DATABASE_PORT=3306
SYMFONY__DATABASE_USER=root
```

My config.yml contains the following configuration:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
```

On my ec2 machine `printenv | grep SYMFONY` prints the same as above.

[image: My elastic beanstalk environment variables]

But i get the following error message

```
$ sudo bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force 

[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]
      You have requested a non-existent parameter "database_host".
```

EDIT: oh and phpinfo(); printes them too. Don't mind the double host and name variables. I tried something.
[image]

Comment: In my EC2 instances I am using it like this database_driver: '%env.database.driver%' etc. Maybe it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a clean deploy, terminated the ec2 instance and let elastic beanstalk rebuild the ec2 instance.

After that everything worked fine. Maybe i changed some chmods.